# entity_create always returns False

Tags: entities

I'm stuck with trying to get my head around entities, and as I was following [This tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/build-custom-entities-drupal-setup/), I ran into some troubles with this page callback method:

```
 $projects = entity_load('project', array(1, 2, 3));

 if (!isset($projects[3])) {
   $entity = entity_create('project', array('id' => 3));
   $entity->name = t('Spring House');
   $entity->description = t('Some more lipsum.');
   $entity->save();
 }

 dpm($projects);

 return 'Some string';
```

Opening my page, I get

> `Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::save() in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/expoline/sites/all/modules/demo/demo.module
>   on line 52`

This leads me to believe that my entity is never created. Any reason why this might be happening?

EDIT:
My hook_entity_info() function

```
/**
 * Implements hook_entity_info().
 */
function demo_entity_info() {

  $info = array();

  $info['project'] = array(
    'label' => t('Project'),
    'base table' => 'demo_projects',
    'entity keys' => array(
      'id' => 'id',
      'label' => 'name',
    ),
    'entity class' => 'Entity',
    'controller class' => 'ProjectEntityController',
    'module' => 'demo',
  );

  return $info;
}
```

Comment: Have you enabled entity API https://www.drupal.org/project/entity contrib module?

Comment: Yup, it's enabled. Even tried reinstalling it, to no avail.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! May you show the code you are using for `hook_entity_info()` too?

Comment: What's the `project` entity, and how have you/its author provided integration with the entity module?

Comment: Thanks :) I've edited my question with my hook_entity_info() function.

Comment: So, it randomly started working. I have no idea what I did, what caused it to work, or what caused it to break..